# Name of type of Matrix

Tags: matrices

I am struggling to remember the name of this type of Matrix.
Could anyone assist?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the transpose of the incidence matrix of $K_5$, the complete graph on $5$ vertices.